# GridView does not cover background if totalWidth is not dividable by crossAxisCount

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I created a GridView with `crossAxisCount: 3`. The problem is that if the totalWidth of the GridView is not dividable by 3, the background will shine through the GridView resulting in like the background colored lines visible on the GridView. Is there a way to avoid it?

Note: Problem does not appear on mobile

Code for Reproduction:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          width: 301,
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried your code but not visible any colored lines my side, can you please provide whole code

Comment: This is the whole code. But maybe it has to do with the platform. I ran it on DartPad.

Comment: Yeah, it works on mobile but not on web, windows. These two I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be removed using `border`.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Yeah. of course such workarounds work. I wondered if there was a better way but probably not. I wanted to make sure that this really is a bug before opening a GitHub issue.

Comment: I've seen this issue on GitHub and also asked on this site, BT can't find links now.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var responsive = MediaQuery.of(context).size; // add this line
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: responsive.width, // add this line
        height: responsive.height, // add this line
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
              Container( // change content to view borders og grid
                decoration: BoxDecoration( // add this line
                  border: Border.all( // add this line
                    color: Colors.white, // add this line
                    width: 1, // add this line
                  ), // add this line
                  color: Colors.black, // add this line
                ), // add this line
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result will be as this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or you can just put value border **width = 0.0**

```
SizedBox(
        width: 301,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 0.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```